# If one-one, then the sequence is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have a question that I would like some hints on how to solve:

Suppose $(a_n)$, a sequence in a metric space $X$, converges to $L \in X$. Show, if $\sigma: \mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is one-one, then the sequence $(a_{σ(n)})_n$ also converges to $L$.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Hint: Can you show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sigma(n)=+\infty$?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: if $\sigma$ is injective, then for all $k\geq 0$, there exists an $M>0$ such that $\sigma(n)>k$ for all $n\geq M$.

(This can be proved by noting that the set of $l\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\sigma(l)\leq k$ is finite, as otherwise $\sigma$ would not be injective.)

Comment: I'm confused. Where did your hint come from? How does it follow from the definition of an injective function?

Comment: Have a look at the definition of a convergent sequence, it might be a little more clear why $M$ will help you choose a sufficient natural number for each $\epsilon >0$.

Comment: This can be proved by noting that the set of l∈ℕ such that σ(l)≤k is finite, as otherwise σ would not be injective. Why would this mean that σ would not be injective if the preceding hint were not true?